# How to get font size of blf module?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

`blf` module has an API to change font size.
By this API, I usually change font size and draw text.

However, I could not find the API to **get** font size.
Getting font size is useful to revert the font size to original.
Is there any methods to get current font size from Python API?

I will use this method for realizing below codes.

```py
orig_font_size = blf.get_font_size()    # this API does not exist!

blf.size(0, 22, dpi)
blf.draw(...)

# revert to original font size
blf.size(0, orig_font_size, dpi)
blf.draw(...)
```

Instead, do we need to add API to Blender to realize this?

Thanks!